# Sum a single column of values in a 2d array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, sum

I am trying to sum all the `SELECT COUNT` from DB in order to get the total hour worked by an employee.
`$theWeek` contains the days of current week in timestamp format, and `$vendeur` is the employee id got from HTML and JS.

This is what i get when i `print_r($weekStat)`, which is fine because on Wednesday (key n°2) the employee worked 6 hours and the rest 0:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sum_count] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sum_count] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sum_count] => 6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [sum_count] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [sum_count] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [sum_count] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [sum_count] => 0
        )

)
```

The problem is when I `echo($total);` & `echo((int)$value);` I get `0` for each `$total` and only `1` for each `$value`. i need to get `$total = 6`

Here is my code :

```
     function getHisStats($vendeur, $theWeek){
        $connexion = connexion();
        $weekStat = array(); // stock les plannings de chaque semaine
 
        $somme = 0;
        $total = 0;

        // On récupere chaque jour de la semaine et on assigne un planning à chaque jour
        for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++){
            // Creating YY-MM-DD format for fetch in DB
            $dateCurrent = getdate($theWeek[$i]);
            $day = $dateCurrent['mday'];
            $month = $dateCurrent['mon'];
            $year = $dateCurrent['year'];

            // Used to fetch date
            $jour = $year. '-' . $month . '-' . $day;

            // Counting the number of instances of id_planning
            $request_travail = $connexion->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id_planning) AS sum_count FROM plannings WHERE id_employe = ? AND date_planning = ? AND (id_affectation = ? OR id_affectation = ? OR id_affectation = ? OR id_affectation = ?) AND id_validation = ?");
            $request_travail->execute(array($vendeur, $jour, 0, 2, 8, 9, 1));
            $resultat_travail = $request_travail->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            // Stocking the results
            array_push($weekStat, $resultat_travail[0]);
        }
        foreach($weekStat as $key => $value){
            echo($total); // I get 7 at the end because $value is always = 1
            echo((int)$value); // I get 1 everytime
            $total = $total + (int)$value;
        }
        return $weekStat;
    }
```

Comment: It’s because you are trying to cast an _array_ of the form `['sum_count' => 6]` “to int”, which does not make much sense. You should properly access the _value_ contained in that array under the _key_ `sum_count`.

Comment: This is legitimately an off-topic typo question.  You know how to access elements, you just failed to do so properly in your foreach loop.   This page is screaming out for a refactor/cleanup, but if you want that, take your working code to [codereview.se].  First, you should only make one trip to the db, but there are many parts of this script to refine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When recording the individual results, you are adding the row of data each time.  As  the only value you use is `sum_count`, you can add this value directly instead

```
array_push($weekStat, $resultat_travail[0]['sum_count']);
```

You should then be able to use `array_sum()` instead of a loop to calculate the total...

```
$total = array_sum($weekStat);
```

You may also be able to do the sum in SQL instead, which may be worth looking into.